# Joomla application redirection in new window

Tags: php, joomla

How can i transform this redirection :

$app->redirect('http://www.yourwebsite.com');

in new window redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this in php. But in javascript you can do:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=javascript:window.open('http://www.yourwebsite.com','_parent');">
```

If it was just a link then simply adding `target="_blank"` to the `<a>` tag would work.